# Binomial coefficient

Tags: c++, algorithm, combinatorics

I wrote a C++ function to calculate the binomial coefficient, trying to avoid overflows as much as possible.

```
/*!
 * @brief Calculates the binomial coefficient indexed by n and k
 *
 * This implementation is based on the algorithm described here: http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html
 * and the relevant follow-up: http://blog.plover.com/math/choose-2.html
 *
 * @param n                     The number of elements
 * @param k                     The number of elements in each subset
 * @return                      The number of k-element subsets in a n-element set
 *
 * @throw std::overflow_error   If the computation caused an overflow
 */
uint64_t binomial_coefficient(uint64_t n, uint64_t k)
{
    if (k > n)
        return 0;

    if (n - k < k)
        k = n - k;

    uint64_t r = 1;

    for (uint64_t d = 1; d <= k; d++)
    {
        uint64_t mult = n;

        bool divided = true;

        if (mult % d == 0)
            mult /= d;
        else if (r % d == 0)
            r /= d;
        else
            divided = false;

        const uint64_t r_mult = r * mult;
        if (r_mult / mult != r)
            throw std::overflow_error("Overflow");

        r = r_mult;

        if (!divided)
            r /= d;

        n--;
    }

    return r;
}
```

I have implemented the algorithm described [here](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose.html) with a slight modification (**try** to divide `n` or `r` by `d` before multiplying `n` by `r`) as described in the article [follow-up](http://blog.plover.com/math/choose-2.html).

I also added an overflow check, which I believe should be reliable, as unsigned arithmetic overflow [should not yield undefined behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188846/671092).

Do you see any blatant or subtle bug in my implementation, and/or any room for improvement (besides lookup tables for common values and alike, which I am not willing to pursue at the moment)?

Comment: Just so you know, binomial coefficients have a very naturally occurring lookup table: Pascal's Triangle. Using the triangle is actually a better way to calculate binomial coefficients for smaller n and k, and you get memoization for free if you implement it right.

Comment: did you look at [Boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/factorials/sf_binomial.html)?

Comment: @TemplateRex: Would that also suggest that the OP's function should return a floating-point type?

Comment: @Jamal good point, I wrote my own for that reason. My comment was to let the OP make his requirements / Rationale explicit

Comment: @TemplateRex: I was trying to come up with something simpler (not incorporating Boost since I'm not too familiar with it), but I couldn't quite think of anything good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- An exception message should tell some details of the overflow (at least values of `n` and `k`)
- The function begs to be templated.

The rest is not a review, but rather a long comment.

I don't think the algorithm achieves the declared goal (to avoid overflows *as much as possible*): an overflow occurs in the intermediate result (`r_mult`), even though an actual result (`r`) could very well fit `uint64_t` after division.

A root of the problem lies in an opportunistic approach. Factors are reduced only if one of them is divisible by `d`. The fact is, they can be reduced even if they are not. Surely they are divisible by a greatest common factor:

```
    uint64_t result = 1;

    for (uint64_t d = 1; d <= k; d++)
    {
        uint64_t num = n - k + d;
        uint64_t denom = d;

        uint64_t common_factor = gcd(result, denom);

        result /= common_factor;
        denom /= common_factor;

        assert(num % denom == 0);
        num /= denom;

        if (result > UINT64_MAX / num) {
            throw std::overflow_error("Overflow");
        }

        result *= num;
    }

    return result;
```

PS: it could be mathematically proven that the assertion never triggers.

Comment: Regarding the first point, would the `if` block here also need to display `n` and `k` (probably via `std::cerr`)?  Or can all of that be passed into `std::overflow_error()`?

Comment: vnp: thank you!
@Jamal: I do think that one shall *never* print anything in a function supposed to do... computations (don't touch my streams!). Exceptions exist for the very purpose of handling errors at the right  time, don't they.

Comment: @gd1: That is true.  I just haven't been using exception classes much yet.

Answer (score 8):

Mostly minor things, but could still be helpful:

- Functions should generally be named in a verb form, so rename the function to something like `calculate_binomial_coefficient()`.
- This is a little hard to read:

  > ```
  > if (r_mult / mult != r)
  > ```

  and could use more parenthesis for clarity:

  ```
  if ((r_mult / mult) != r)
  ```
- Consider using curly braces for these single-line conditional statements.  It could also help with avoiding some additional bugs, if you end up adding anything to them.
- Since this is C++ and not C, use `std::uint64_t`.  Try to use all the equivalents that are found in the `std` namespace.

Comment: I think using the `std` namespace on typedefs is unnecessarily verbose. Otherwise I agree.

Comment: @Rapptz: In which way does the fact that a type is actually a typedef change the way it should be qualified?